# Trigger to synchronize Activities with Cases

Tags: trigger

Create an Activity when a case is registered and send a notification mail to the activity owner. The following Activity fields are to be populated from the Case Record.

Subject Case having “Case Subject” under “Case Reason”
Assigned To Account Owner of the Account to which the case belongs
Related to  Account to which the case belongs
Priority    Set to High
Due Date    Date/Time Closed of the case

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow rule under case object to send an email alert as well as create a task. Write a trigger upon task creation and populate with the Account to which the case belongs. Hope this helps.